# Code-First MVC - Where are AspNet tables implemented?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

I am creating a **Code First** MVC project and I have a question relating to SQL tables being automatically implemented.

**Background:**

Whilst creating my project I Implemented a table to store Movie Details (in SeedData.cs). There is no mention of any other tables in there. However, when you look at the Database with the new Movie Table, there are also multiple AspNet tables such as AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles.

**Question**

As Code-First means that the Code is implemented before the Entities/Tables, surely AspNet tables should already be declared/accessible in my project?

Since I assume they were created automatically, does anybody know where these tables are implemented when you create a Code-First MVC Project?

Comment: I don't think you need to access AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles yourself. They're used internally by the ASP.Net Identity services to store data about user logins. If your site has login functionality that's when they'll have been created, I think. Nothing to do with whether you use CodeFirst or not.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks I do have login functionalities so they should have been created then. This is my first time writing anything Code-First  and I wasn't sure if it made a difference with creation.

Comment: no problem, happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Visual Studio Templates to create a project, when you create the project there was a tick box selection for if you required User Authentification. You have selected yes and that is why the ASPNET Users Roles etc have been added to your project.

Hope this helps.